# Detect Antivirus through WMI

Tags: windows, wmi, detection, antivirus

I have come up with a situation in which an installed antivirus is not detected by wmic or it's equivalent cmdlet. The system where I am having this issue is a windows server 2016 and the antivirus is SEP (Symantec Endpoint Protection)

While doing some research I have found two possible explanations for this, but as far as I understood, these answers are pretty different, actually could even be complementary. Since I am a newcomer to WMI I would like some clarification about them.

The command I am using for retrieving the information is:

```
wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path antivirusproduct GET ...
```

The first explanation<sup>1</sup> I found is that the antivirusproduct class is not defined in server versions of windows which fits my problem since my machine is a windows server and I have tried the same command on a Win10 machine and it works.

The second explanation<sup>2</sup> talks about the fact that in order to detect the antivirus through WMI it has to be registered on the Windows Security Center.

Having said that the main questions are:

Is the antivirusprocut class defined by the Windows Security Center provider, actually, does WSC have a WMI provider. If not which WMI provider is defining this class. I have been looking at the list of providers in the reference documentation<sup>3</sup> and there doesn't seem to be a provider defining this so I assume this must be set by a provider coming from a third party software, hence the guess about WSC.

Regardless of the provider why would a class be defined on windows desktop versions and not on a server ones.

Any clarification is appreciated.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Detecting anti-virus on Windows with WMI - which namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710027/detecting-anti-virus-on-windows-with-wmi-which-namespace)

<sup>2</sup> https://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/commands/wmic/determine-antivirus.php

<sup>3</sup> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-providers